# Remaping topics doesn't work

Tags: ros, remap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi I'm using Ros and I have some Camera-Data on topic

```
    /kinect2/sd/points
```

now I want to remap them to

```
      /camera/depth/points
```

Here the code I use:

```
<include file="$(find kinect2_bridge)/launch/kinect2_bridge.launch">
    <param name = "_depth_method"   value="cuda" />
    <param name = "_reg_method"     value="cpu" />
    <remap from="/camera/depth/points"  to="/kinect2/sd/points"/> 
</include>
```

Now if I listen with "rotopic echo" to the topic of "kinect2/sd/points" I got many output. But if I listen to the topic "/camera/depth/points" I get no Data.

Can anybody help me is the order of the remap right=?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/247870/remaping-topics-doesn%27t-work/) by [eed](https://answers.ros.org/users/26667/eed/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2016-11-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on 2016-11-12**:
You want to map from */kinect2/sd/points* to */camera/depth/points* and you have

you need

They're the wrong way around

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You won't get output. The topic, as you mentioned, has been remapped. The node doesn't duplicate the data

If you want to duplicate the topic then use relay:

http://wiki.ros.org/topic_tools/relay

Mark

---

Originally posted by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) with karma: 1834 on 2016-11-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1